# How to pass file location if folder name contains space and file name has timestamp in Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, database-backups

Here is the batch file where I am trying for normal export backup but it is not working due to space in folder name `DB Backup` for Backup file directory in `file="D:\DB Backup\sys_12c_%fullstamp%.dmp"`. It works file if there in no space in folder name i.e. `DBBackup`.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%_%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
exp system/manager full=y file="D:\DB Backup\sys_12c_%fullstamp%.dmp" log="D:\DB Backup\sys_12c_%fullstamp%.log"
```

Comment: The quotes are correct, so it looks like a problem in your `exp` program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use triple quoting:

```bat
exp system/manager full=y file="""D:\DB Backup\sys_12c_%fullstamp%.dmp""" log="""D:\DB Backup\sys_12c_%fullstamp%.log"""
```

Comment: But why should it work with three quotes? Do you know the `exp` program?

Comment: @jeb, I found it squirrelled away in [Chapter 7 of the Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E69230_12/otn/pdf/install/html_agaba/output/chapter_7.htm), _more specifically, 7.3.3.2 Exporting the Full Oracle Database._